# Data Loader Permission Sets

Tags: data-loader, permission-sets

I need to create a permission set for a member of staff to use dataloader. I created the permission set with license set to none so that I can assign to users with different rights.

I then assigned that permission set to a member of staff but I can't work out how to do the bit below?

Any help gratefully appreciated. I am not a Salesforce Administrator but the CEO of a charity trying my best to figure this out!! Thanks

> Data Loader
>
> Importing records with Data Loader requires these permissions.
>
> “Read,” “Create,” “Edit,” and “Delete” on the objects
>
> “API Enabled”
>
> “Bulk API Hard Delete” (only if you configure Data Loader to use Bulk API to hard-delete records)

Comment: Is the user in question experiencing an error when they try to download, install, or use the Data Loader? What error do they get? Or, are they unable to download the Data Loader at all? The permissions that the user has while editing records normally are the same as the Data Loader requires, so they may not need any extra permissions. We need to know more in order to help you. Please read about the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to understand why I'm asking these questions. You can [edit] additional information in to your question. Looking forward to helping you out!